# MySQL: merging rows

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a MySQL table like this one:

| id | name | surname | score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | smith | 15 |
| 2 | john | black | 10 |
| 3 | albert | black | 5 |
| 4 | john | smith | 20 |

There can be multiple rows with the same `name` and `surname` combination.
How can I extract data so that the scores are added when the `name` and `surname` are the same?

The outcome I'm looking for is:

| name | surname | added scores |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | smith | 35 |
| john | black | 10 |
| albert | black | 5 |

Comment: This is a basic `SUM(score)` and `GROUP BY` query. What problem are you having?

Comment: @Barmar, thank you, I didn't know how to start

Comment: It should be in any SQL tutorial, it's one of the most common things to do.